# Create unique incremental id and add it to the set

Tags: java, set, unique-id

The problem is that I need to create new incremental ID for each new customer and add it to the Set, I'm trying to do it with the while loop, but it seems not to be right

```
public class Bank {

    private String name;

    private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<Customer>();


    private Set<AbstractAccount> accounts = new HashSet<AbstractAccount>();

    private Integer lastCustomerId = 0;

    private Integer lastAccountId = 0;

    public Integer addCustomer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        // generate id from lastCustomerId and increment it
        // add to Set
        return lastCustomerId++; 
    }

    public Integer addAccount(Integer ownerId, AccountType type) {
        // add to Set
    }       



}
```

Comment: Where is your `while` loop?

Comment: You have declared lastCustomerId and lastAccountId, I guess just for that reason. So use them. When adding a new customer, increment the lastCustomerId and return it. When adding a new account do it analogically. What is the problem really?

Comment: one minute - I'll add it

Comment: the aim is to create an automatic method - when adding a new customer, the id should be created and this customer added to the set

Comment: user3047466 edit your question, don't paste comments to clarify the question.

Comment: the problem is that with just returning lastCustomerId++  - when adding a new customer the 0 will become 1,so this is not enough, even         the HashSet doesn't contain dublicates.Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if is that what you want...

```
public class Bank
{

    private String name;

   private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<Customer>();


    private Set<AbstractAccount> accounts = new HashSet<AbstractAccount>();


    private static int lastCustomerId = 0;
    private static int lastAccountId = 0;

    public static int GetNextCustomerID()
    {
        lastCustomerId++;
        return lastCustomerId;
    }

    public static int GetNextAccountID()
    {
        lastAccountId++;
        return lastAccountId;
    }

    public int addCustomer(String firstName, String lastName) 
    {
       // generate id from lastCustomerId and increment it
        int customerId = GetNextCustomerID();
        // add to Set
    }

    public int addAccount(int ownerId, AccountType type) 
    {
        // add to Set
        int accountId = GetNextAccountID();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes,that's what I was looking for, just else return customerId should be added. And then I need to add it to the set, but I have tried add(new Customer(customerId, firstName, lastName));    - but it doesn't work